# Loading a class in Java

Tags: java, classloader

I would like to load a class that is located within another project; following the structure of my packages, projects etc.:

```
--ProjectA
  --package myPackageA
    --myClassA

 --ProjectB
  --package myPackageB
    --myClassB
      --myMethodB
```

Within myMethodB, I want to load the class "myClassA" from ProjectA. 
I know how to load the class if it were within ProjectB, but I don't know how to reference it with my current structure.

The only thing I have so far is following:

```
Class<?> c = thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass("location_of_myClassA");
```

In short: What do I write instead of "location_of_myClassA"?

Comment: This smells a lot like The Wrong Way to do something. What is it you're trying to do, exactly, that hard coding this makes sense?

Comment: Actually I just wanted to know how to reference a class in a package in another project, and this seemed the best way to ask how to do it. :)

Comment: "Another project" does not make sense outside an IDE.

Comment: ProjectA is not outside my Eclipse environment, it's just another project, but connected to ProjectB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the classloader knows about both of them, you *just* need to give the fully-qualified class name:

```
...loadClass("myPackageA.myClassA")
```

`ClassLoader.loadClass` doesn't need to be given a "location" - that's part of how it's *initialized* (e.g. to point to a particular jar file or set of jar files).

Comment: Wow, didn't think it would be that easy. Thank you very much, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse,

```
Right Click Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Project References
```

Select the projects you want to refer

For Netbeans,

```
Right Click Project -> Properties -> Libraries -> Add Project(Compile Tab)
```

Select projects.

Answer (score 0):

As long as all the .class files are in your classpath (or in .jar files within your classpath), you shouldn't have to do anything but:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName(classname);
```

Of course this uses the default system classloader (which is controlled by the jvm's "java.class.path" setting, ie.  the "-cp" argument on java executable).

Aside from that you can use the Context ClassLoader as above, or use the same classloader that loaded some other specific class:

```
// within an instance method
Class<?> c = getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(classname)

// within some other object (other than SomeClass), or a static method:
Class<?> c = SomeClass.class.getClassLoader().loadClass(classname);
```

In a typical command line application, all 3 of these would essentially be the same since there is only the system classloader (unless the app is explicitly replacing the classloader).  However, in a web app, the servlet container usually provides customized classloaders to keep separate classpaths for each web app, so there is a difference in which one you want to call (I won't get into the specifics here).

If calling one of these does not work for you, it means the class you're trying to load is not in one of your classpath entries, and perhaps the problem is your IDE setup (maybe you didn't add project a to project b's classpath), or your maven setup (you didn't define a dependency on project a in project b).

Answer (score -1):

You can always try using JARMaker to jar ProjectA and use it as a library in ProjectB